# Overflow appearing on mobile devices, but not in local enviornment

Tags: html, css, grid, overflow

[This page](https://bluebugx.github.io/public-assets/) is giving a horizontal scroll on mobile devices, but it shouldn't. Also when I'm testing it offline, it is working fine. even Chrome simulator is showing fine. As soon as I put it in github or anywhere else, it's getting this horizontal scroll. Please help me to spot what is causing it. Thanks.
https://bluebugx.github.io/public-assets/

Comment: Hmmm I just tried your page on my phone and it's not giving me horizontal scroll.

Comment: No horizontal scroll on IOS on iPad either with Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Then I guess it's some rendering problem specific to GitHub and codepen. Thanks guys for testing it.